# Ошибки при компиляции алгоритма Дейкстры

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net

Ошибки при компиляции

Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term 'int'
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected
Error   CS0103  The name 'generalWeight' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'generalWeight' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
Error   CS0103  The name 'changeVisible' does not exist in the current context

Код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DayxtraAlgorithm.View;
using DayxtraAlgorithm.Model;
using DayxtraAlgorithm.Util;


namespace cproject
{
    public partial class traningForm : Form
    {
        Graph graph;
        public traningForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void c111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void b123_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void shortgraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var first = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) - 1;
            var second = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text) - 1;
            var count = graph.matrix.Count;
            var vertEntities = Creator.createVertexEntities(count);
            var shortestWay = Dayxtra.getShortestWay(graph.matrix, graph.weight, vertEntities, out int generalWeight, first, second);
            label8.Text = "Вес: " + generalWeight.ToString();
            pictureBox2.Image = GraphDisplayer.draw(pictureBox2.Height, pictureBox2.Width, graph, shortestWay);
        }

        private void graph_generation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count;
            int posib = textBox4.Text; // отсюда берется число. если написать на форме 20, значит для программы означает 20% т.е. указывается число без знака процента
            if (!Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out count))
            {
                count = 5;
            }
            graph = Creator.createNonDirected(count, posib);
            Creator.createWeight(graph, 5, 20);

            pictureBox2.Image = GraphDisplayer.draw(pictureBox2.Height, pictureBox2.Width, graph);
            changeVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Dayxtra]

Ссылка на DayxtraAlgorithm.Util.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DayxtraAlgorithm.Model;

namespace DayxtraAlgorithm.Util
{
    public static class Dayxtra
    {
        public static List<int> getShortestWay(List<List<byte?>> matrix, List<List<string>> weight,
            List<VertexEntity> vertexes, out int generalWeight, int first = 0, int second = 0)
        {
            var firstVert = vertexes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Num == first);
            firstVert.setDist(0);

            if (second == 0)
                second = matrix.Count - 1;

            var finalVert = vertexes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Num == second);

            while(!finalVert.isSetted)
            {
                var vertex = vertexes.FindAll(x => !x.isSetted).Min();
                int rowNum = vertex.Num;
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix[rowNum].Count; i++)
                {
                    if (matrix[rowNum][i] == 1 && !vertexes[i].isSetted)
                    {
                        setVertex(vertex, vertexes[i], weight[rowNum][i]);
                    }
                    else if (matrix[i][rowNum] == 1 && !vertexes[i].isSetted)
                    {
                        setVertex(vertex, vertexes[i], weight[i][rowNum]);
                    }
                }
                vertex.isSetted = true;

            }

            return getWayBetween(vertexes, out generalWeight, first, second);

        }

        private static void setVertex(VertexEntity vertex, VertexEntity ChildVertex, string weight)
        {
            var newDist = vertex.Dist + Int32.Parse(weight);
            if (ChildVertex.Dist > newDist)
            {
                ChildVertex.setDist(newDist);
                ChildVertex.setPrev(vertex);
            }
        }
        private static List<int> getWayBetween(List<VertexEntity> vertexes, out int genWeight, 
            int first, int second)
        {
            List<int> shortestWay = new List<int>();
            var vertex = vertexes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Num == second);
            var vertexStart = vertexes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Num == first);
            genWeight = vertex.Dist;

            while (vertex != null)
            {
                shortestWay.Add(vertex.Num);
                vertex = vertex.Prev;
            }

            return shortestWay;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Помогите исправить ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

C# 6 и ранее:

```
int generalWeight;  
var shortestWay = Dayxtra.getShortestWay(graph.matrix, graph.weight, vertEntities, 
    out generalWeight, first, second);
```

C# 7:

```
var shortestWay = Dayxtra.getShortestWay(graph.matrix, graph.weight, vertEntities, 
    out int generalWeight, first, second);
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

---

В форме отсутствует метод `changeVisible`.

---

```
int posib = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
```

---

В сообщениях об ошибке указывается номер строки кода. Вам следует включить эту информацию в вопрос - не номер строки, конечно, а указание, в какой строке кода происходит ошибка.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' 53(строка). изначалльно:
int posib = trackBar1.Value; переделал в int posib = textBox4.Text; // из textBox4 идет считывание из поля. если написать на форме в textbox4 20, значит для программы означает 20% т.е. указывается число без знака процента.